# Who is Leah, exactly?

Tags: diablo-iii

Leah is kind of a central NPC in Diablo 3, and she seems to have an extensive history with Deckard Cain, often calling him "Uncle."

However, the game is pretty light on details as to who she is, precisely.  It's clear she's not ordinary, for instance:

> 2/3rds of the way through Act 1, she shows some awe-inspiring, but uncontrolled supernatural powers.

I'm not super familiar with Diablo lore on the whole, having only played Diablo 2 for a few months many years ago.  Who is Leah?  What's her role in the Diablo saga?

Comment: I would say that you haven't played enough of Diablo 3 to understand Leah's role in the lore.

Comment: Her mother was a witch, remember. Power tends to be inherited, and Leah will tell you a little while later that she's always had this power.

Comment: Didn't you listen to Yoda? Leah is your sister! To make it worse, you're both the children of Darth Vader!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leah is referred to as [the adopted daughter](http://www.diablowiki.net/Leah) and the niece of Deckard Cain, but she is actually [the daughter of Adria the witch and Prince Aiden](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Leah) which makes her the granddaughter of King Leoric ([AKA the Skeleton King](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/King_Leoric) ).  Recall that Diablo attempted to possess Leoric, failed because he was too weak, then possessed his young son [Prince Albrecht](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Albrecht) - Leah's uncle.  Suffice it to say, the family has some bad luck.

**Edit:**

I recently found out that if you'd like to know more about how Cain and Leah met, there is a book from Blizzard called [Diablo III: The Order](http://www.blizzplanet.com/blog/comments/blizzplanet-review-diablo-iii-the-order) which details there meeting and a whole lot of backstory leading up to Diablo III.  Sadly it seems pretty light on details of [what became of the heroes from Diablo II](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67281/what-happened-to-the-heroes-from-diablo-2) - at least based on the reviews I've read.

Answer (score 3):

She is the daughter of Aiden and Adria. She is also the granddaughter of King Leoric.

> Leah then is trained by Adria to harness the power of the black
>  soulstone in which Azmodan and Belial will get trapped. **Then Adria
>  will reveal that Leah is her and Diablo's daughter**, and will fuse
>  the black soulstone with Leah to make her become Diablo as the prime evel, holding together all the souls of all the evils. When Diablo is slain, no trace of Leah's fate is told.

[source](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Leah)

Answer (score 2):

She's [Adria's](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Adria) daughter. You may remember Adria as the village witch from the first Diablo game. Adria entrusted Leah to be raised by Deckard Cain for reasons that are revealed as the game progresses.

Comment: BUT WHO'S THE FATHER?  WHY ISN'T THERE ANY ALIMONY?

Comment: Hey, my name's Leah - and this is crazy, my uncles missing... so save him, maybe?