# Do the Diablo 2 characters appear in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the heroes from Diablo 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67281/what-happened-to-the-heroes-from-diablo-2)

Diablo 1 and 2 spoiler below. If you haven't already played and finished one and two you need to relive your childhood.

> The three player classes from Diablo 1 (Warrior, Rogue, Sorcerer) appear in Diablo 2 (Dark Wanderer, Blood Raven, Summoner). Do the 5 (or 7) player classes from Diablo 2 appear in Diablo 3?

If yes, where can they be found?

Comment: The barbarian in Diablo III is the same class from D2 but with different abilities. Afaik the other classes don't have a cameo in D3

Comment: I hadn't realized the connection between the Summoner and Blood Raven. I only knew about the Dark Wanderer, who was pretty obvious given that he's a central character. Neat!